# How to calculate a cubic function using the Vietea's formula in Java?

Tags: java, math

I have to write a program in which I write a,b c,d (coefficients of equation 3 degree) and as a result I should get X1, X2, X3 (solutions of equation). I have to use Viete's formulas and BigDecimal for this, because my lecturer requires it from me.

I came to the conclusion that I have to solve the following system of equations:

```
x1+x2+x3=-b/a
x1*x2+x1*x3+x2*x3=c/a
x1*x2*x3=-d/a
```

I have no idea how I can do it in Java.
I tried to use the JAMA package, but I don't think I can use it to solve such a system of equations.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find the roots of a cubic polynomial in Java you can do it easily using Newton-Raphson's method.

**The algorithm -**

```
 1. Input: initial x, func(x), derivFunc(x)
    Output: Root of Func()
 2. Compute values of func(x) and derivFunc(x) for given initial x
 3. Compute h: h = func(x) / derivFunc(x)
 4. While h is greater than allowed error ε
       - h = func(x) / derivFunc(x)
       - x = x – h
```

Here is a demonstration for solving the cubic equation x^3-x^2+2

```java
class XYZ { 

    static final double EPSILON = 0.001; 

    // An example function whose solution 
    // is determined using Bisection Method. 
    // The function is x^3 - x^2 + 2 
    static double func(double x) 
    { 
        return x * x * x - x * x + 2; 
    } 

    // Derivative of the above function  
    // which is 3*x^x - 2*x 
    static double derivFunc(double x) 
    { 
        return 3 * x * x - 2 * x; 
    } 

    // Function to find the root 
    static void newtonRaphson(double x) 
    { 
        double h = func(x) / derivFunc(x); 
        while (Math.abs(h) >= EPSILON) 
        { 
            h = func(x) / derivFunc(x); 

            // x(i+1) = x(i) - f(x) / f'(x)  
            x = x - h; 
        } 

        System.out.print("The value of the"
                + " root is : " 
                + Math.round(x * 100.0) / 100.0); 
    } 

    // Driver code 
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    { 

        // Initial values assumed 
        double x0 = -20;  
        newtonRaphson(x0); 
    } 
}
```

Output - The value of root is : -1.00

To do it your way you have to solve a system of non-linear equations which is harder but can be done using the Newton Raphson's Multivariate method. You might want to look it up. Also note that this is an approximate method and guesses the roots after you put an initial 'guess' of your own (in this case its -20)

Answer (score 0):

The Newton (Raphson, Kantorovich) method for the Viete equations gives you the (Weierstrass-)Durand-Kerner method of simultaneous root approximation. However, in the completed method you will no longer see the Viete identities, they kind of cancel out. You will need complex numbers over the demanded real numbers data type.

If you go with the simple Newton method like in the other answer, then after computing the one real root you can split off the linear factor belonging to it via the Horner-Ruffini scheme and then solve the remaining quadratic equation directly. Then you only need to consider the possible complex nature of the roots in constructing the output strings, as the real and imaginary parts have easy direct formulas.